# Html5 audio Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Hi guys i tried to do player with playlist but have troubles with Chrome.
This code doesn't  work in Chrome. I can't understand why,  because all another brouser work fine.

```
<audio id="PlayaBle" src="music/Kalimba.mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="Y">
    Your browser does not support HTML5
</audio>

<button id="Next">Next sound</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var audio=$('#PlayaBle');

        $('#Next').click(function(){
            audio.attr('src','music/Sleep Away.mp3')
            audio[0].pause();
            audio[0].load();
            audio[0].play();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get some error? Nothing in the console? Anyway, your audio element has some wrong attributes, it should look like `<audio id="PlayaBle" src="music/Kalimba.mp3" controls autoplay>`. [Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/audio) Docs for more information.

Comment: @kmsdev Definition is fine. As long as `controls` and `autoplay` are set, it doesn't matter what values they have

Comment: I knew it works but it hurts my eyes! Referring to errors, maybe the console outputs something... But @JqueryKing has the correct answer already.

Comment: Console clear. Trouble just in this song 'Sleep Away.mp3', but only in Chrome :D  Who knows which one songs have the same.

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

You have space between the src text `'music/Sleep Away.mp3'`;

and code be

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

$('#Next').click(function(){
             audioElement.pause();
             audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'music/Sleep_Away.mp3');
             audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
              audioElement.play();
             }, true);
});
```

Comment: I though about it but problem not with space, problem in some songs, now i had tested more than 10 song with spaces and not, but only windows default song 'Sleep away.mp3 ' not working. Who knows , maybe troubl with some special properties. Ty for answer